# WHERE statement with condition when one column is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have

```
ID       |   Column 1 | Column 2
  2      |      NULL  |     "a"
  3      |      "b"   |    NULL
  4      |       "c"  |     "c"
```

What I want to write is this:

```
 SELECT ID FROM table, AnotherTable 
  WHERE (Table.Column1 = AnotherTable.Column IF Table.Column1 IS NOT NULL 
     OR Table.Column2 = AnotherTable.Column IF Table.Column2 IS NOT NULL)
```

EDIT: I am also adding the case  IF Table.Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Table.Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN CHOOSE Table.Column2 = AnotherTable.Column

Comment: So only 1 of 2 columns can have `null`? It seems that you need full outer join.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
SELECT ID
FROM   table JOIN AnotherTable
               ON AnotherTable.Column = COALESCE(table.Column1, table.Column2)
```

Comment: What if both Column1 and Column2 have values but I only want column 2.

Comment: @user461316: reverse the order of the arguments?